# Exception related to pom while running a job in talend studio 7.3.1

Tags: java, talend

When I try to run a job in talend studio 7.3.1, I get the following error.
There are many jobs in the repository but some jobs are displaying this issue when run. I cannot add the long error message which I got while running the job as stack overflow is not allowing me to copy the entire stack trace. I added the first part of the error message below the screen shot.

[image]

```
org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorException: java.lang.Exception: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module C:\Users\tomgeorg\Documents\TalendRemoteWorkspace\.repositories\743898097\branches\ICE_DATASOURCING_DEV\HP_ICE_DATASRC_DEV\poms\jobs\joblets_spark\DSRC_GCW\Development\Block2\pr_ams_cross_border_blk2_0.1\pom.xml of C:\Users\tomgeorg\Documents\TalendRemoteWorkspace\.repositories\743898097\branches\ICE_DATASOURCING_DEV\HP_ICE_DATASRC_DEV\poms\build-aggregator.pom does not exist @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.talend:build.aggregator:7.0.0 (C:\Users\tomgeorg\Documents\TalendRemoteWorkspace\.repositories\743898097\branches\ICE_DATASOURCING_DEV\HP_ICE_DATASRC_DEV\poms\build-aggregator.pom) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module C:\Users\tomgeorg\Documents\TalendRemoteWorkspace\.repositories\743898097\branches\ICE_DATASOURCING_DEV\HP_ICE_DATASRC_DEV\poms\jobs\joblets_spark\DSRC_GCW\Development\Block2\pr_ams_cross_border_blk2_0.1\pom.xml of C:\Users\tomgeorg\Documents\TalendRemoteWorkspace\.repositories\743898097\branches\ICE_DATASOURCING_DEV\HP_ICE_DATASRC_DEV\poms\build-aggregator.pom does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Comment: Dumping an unreadable screenshot is hardly asking a question. It is impossible to read the error.

Comment: I don't understand what is unreadable ?. If you click on the picture, the image will get maximized which is readable by all.

Comment: Which, in my 40" monitor, is still unreadable. Please post errors as text with proper formatting so that they are clearly readable (and searchable).

Comment: I have a 23'' Monitor and is clear when the picture opens in maximized mode.

Comment: Thanks for adding the text. You are missing poms in your repo. As you are on windows aren't you exceeding the maxlength of the paths?

Comment: The max length of path is 260 characters right.  The path length given in error message is 211. Also this is generated by Talend( GUI tool) which I don't have a control.

Comment: Well not entirely because you decide where it starts and that is now somewher deep in the users directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have force fully re-synchronized poms and applied the change as per the below screen shot and the issue got resolved.

[image]